# Custom theme based on major mode or file type

Tags: org-mode, themes, customize, multiple-modes

How can I customize emacs to use a different theme based on major mode or file-type? And, could it work to have different themes active in different windows?

My use case would be: have (1) one general them for code and stuff and (2) one special theme (leuven) for org-mode only.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A theme is mostly a set of variable names and values. Enabling a theme means setting each variable to its correspond value in the theme. The variables are changed globally, i.e., for every buffer, window and frame. As a result, you can't have different windows with different themes.

Something you can do though is to have a different font for org-mode. For example, you could use variable pitch:

```
(add-hook 'org-mode-hook (lambda () (variable-pitch-mode t)))
```

Another solution is to have separate Emacs processes (i.e., you start Emacs twice, once for programming, once for org-mode). This can be done (untested) by setting a variable from the command line:

```
emacs --eval="(setq my/for-org t)"
```

And then, your init file could select the theme based on that:

```
(when (bound-and-true-p my/for-org) (load-them 'leuven))
```

Comment: ok, so a command line argument to start emacs with different config files then?

Comment: I've edited my answer

Comment: please mark the answer as correct if you are satisfied.

Comment: sorry, forgot to do that :) thx!

Comment: missing `e` in `(load-theme 'leuven)`